# Find Magnitude of velocity in a collision?

Tags: trigonometry, physics

A baseball and a ball of clay are approaching each other. The mass of the baseball is $145 \ \mathrm{ g }$ and it is moving due west $5 \ \left.\mathrm{ m }\middle/\mathrm{ s }\right.$ at $180^\circ$. The ball of clay is $290 \ \mathrm{ g }$ and it is moving northwest at $135^\circ$ $4 \ \left.\mathrm{ m }\middle/\mathrm{ s }\right.$. What is the magnitude of their combined velocity after they collide and stick together?

I first tried to find velocity in the $x$-direction, then velocity in the $y$-direction, and use the Pythagorean theorem to find total magnitude. I got $3.14 \ \left.\mathrm{ m }\middle/\mathrm{ s }\right.$. Why is this wrong? What should I be doing instead?

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the angle, but what? The only practice I have done was where one object moved straight up.

Comment: Are you taking the masses of the two objects into account?  In your description, it is not clear that you are.

Comment: any number of possibilities, even without considering mass I get a totally different answer. maybe you are thinking of the wrong angles ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this as belonging on Physics SE, because the focus of this question is on kinematics itself, not on the underlying mathematics, such as how to add momenta or calculate the magnitude of a vector.

Answer (score 2):

The momentum $\mathbf{p}$ of an object is given by $m \mathbf{v}$, where $m$ is the mass of that object, and $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity of that object.  Based on your description, the momentum of the baseball is
$$ \mathbf{p}_1 = 145 \langle -5, 0 \rangle $$
and the momentum of the clay is
$$ \mathbf{p}_2 = 290 \left\langle -4\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, 4\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right\rangle = 580 \langle -\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} \rangle $$
(where I have rather lazily elided the units).

Momentum and mass are conserved in the collision of the two objects, thus the resulting momentum is
$$ \mathbf{p}
 = \mathbf{p}_1 + \mathbf{p}_2
 = 145 \langle -5, 0 \rangle + 580 \langle -\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} \rangle
 = \langle -725-580 \sqrt{2}, 580\sqrt{2} \rangle.
$$
Since mass is conserved, it follows that the resulting velocity is
$$ \mathbf{v} = \frac{\mathbf{p}}{m} = \frac{\langle -725-580 \sqrt{2}, 580\sqrt{2} \rangle}{145+290} \approx \langle 3.55, 1.89 \rangle.$$
Note that this is a bit north of due west, which seems reasonable. A little bit of trigonometry could give a more exact heading if we really need it.  From this, it follows that the magnitude of the velocity is
$$\|\mathbf{v}\| = \frac{\mathbf{p}}{m} = \frac{\sqrt{ (725+580 \sqrt{2})^2 +  (580\sqrt{2})^2 }}{145+290} \approx 4.02\ \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}.$$

Comment: If the velocity of the clay is $4~\text{m}/\text{s}$ to the northwest, shouldn't its components be $\langle -2\sqrt{2}~\text{m}/\text{s}, 2\sqrt{2}~\text{m}/\text{s}\rangle$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Oops.  I divided by 2 twice.  Let me fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the law of conservation of momentum. In particular, the combined velocity $v$ can be found using $$145 (-5 \hat{i}) + 290 (-2\sqrt{2} \hat{i} + 2\sqrt{2} \hat{j}) = (145+290) v.$$

Comment: Since the velocity of the clay is $4~\text{m}/\text{s}$ to the northwest, its velocity should be $-2\sqrt{2}\boldsymbol{i} + 2\sqrt{2}\boldsymbol{j}$.

Comment: Thanks! Corrected.